# unique_ptr constructed with reference to rvalue deleter

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() : member(nullptr, &cudaFree) {}
  std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&cudaFree)> member;
}
```

and get the following error in MSVC12:

```
Error   3   error C2338: unique_ptr constructed with reference to rvalue deleter    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory   1382
```

How would I solve this error?

Comment: Seems fine in many other compilers (clang, gcc, VS2015 according to rextester) - likely an old VS compiler problem. Perhaps `member(nullptr, cudaFree)` initialization might work.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, clang, GCC works fine. Don't know about other versions of MSVC. I tried many combinations of &, casting etc. - I could not get it to work. Maybe I should upgrade to MSVC 2015.

Comment: If you can, then that would bet the best regardless of this particular problem - so many things have gotten better! Good luck!

Comment: Turns out I cannot upgrade to VS2015, as I rely on CUDA.

Comment: Try 2013 if you can  - it's also quite different from 2012.

Comment: Unintuitively, MSVC12 is 2013.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, for me VS2013 Update 5 compiles the above code just fine (I just defined a function with a signature equivalent to that of `cudaFree`, like [here](http://rextester.com/JAPRB91278) ). So the problem might be elsewhere. Could you provide an actual MCVE?

Comment: Which CUDA version do you use? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I didn't use any (just look at the code I linked in the previous comment) - can you reproduce the problem without using cuda?

Comment: No, seems like a specific problem related to CUDA and MSVC. For now, I'll just replace the unique pointer with manual memory management and file a bug report. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd rather make a function that calls `cudaFree` than revert to manual memory management. It should avoid any problems with the decorators of `cudaFree` itself. Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a good alternative. Thanks for your help!